# Change a variable within a case statement

Tags: javascript, html

Using JS (jQuery is fine too) ...
is there a way to change a variable *within* a variable using a switch statement?

Rather... How can I set up the variable defined within the case statement to *overwrite* the
****REPLACE-THIS**** that is used as a placeholder variable at the top of the script.

See this fiddle for the usage: [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/6U6S7/1/)

I would rather have a number displayed within the code output (defined by 'count'), rather than the default ****REPLACE-THIS**** as it is doing at this time.

for example...

HTML

```
<div id="phase1" class="phase1">
<h1>Foo | Bar test</h1>

<form name="phase1" >
<ul style="list-style:none;">
<li>Slot 1: <select name="slot1">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select></li>
<li>Slot 2: <select name="slot2">
  <option value="foo">Foo</option>
  <option value="bar">Bar</option>
</select></li>
</ul>
<br />
<input type="button" value="Build" onclick="Build();">
</form>
</div>
<span id="data"></span>
```

JS

```
var count= '**REPLACE-THIS**';
var uniqueID= '<div class="example" id="FooBarDiv'+count+'">';

switch (document.phase1.slot1.value){
  case 'foo':
    slotOne = "Foo1 is:<br>";
    count= '1';
    slotOne +=  uniqueID;
  break;
  case 'bar':
    slotOne = "Bar1 is:<br>";
    count= '1';
    slotOne +=  uniqueID;
  break;
  }

 switch (document.phase1.slot2.value){
  case 'foo':
    slotTwo = "Foo2 is:<br>";
    count= '2';
    slotTwo +=  uniqueID;
  break;
  case 'bar':
    slotTwo = "Bar2 is:<br>";
    count= '2';
    slotTwo +=  uniqueID;
  break;
  }

output = slotOne+slotTwo;
document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=output;
```

Please note, this is a very VERY watered down example. The working example will place a large HTML block onto a page with unique IDs for the tags, based on the selection made with the drop downs.

These IDs will be targeted later with a `getElementbyID` script so, if "FOO" is used twice, the script will still run as expected and call "FooBarDiv1" and "FooBarDiv2" as needed.

Comment: `change a variable within a variable` what does that mean?

Comment: a variable that holds a variable within... fiddle added for clarification

Comment: Does this code not do as you expect? It looks fine at a glance, and you haven't described any problem you encountered. To put it another way: what's the question?

Comment: @AlexWayne - Unfortunately no, it doesn't fire the newly defined variable within the case statement. The output retains the previously declared variable before the switch is initialized. I need the variable to update for each individual switch, and then retain it as needed for output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple replace should suffice.

```
slotOne = slotOne.replace('**REPLACE-THIS**',count);
```

repeat for the rest.
although you should consider creating an array of the elements you are working with.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6U6S7/2/)

As you wish:)

This uses jquery.

```
function Build() {
    var output = "<br>",count= '**REPLACE-THIS**';

    $("#phase1").find("select").each(function(index) {
        output += switcharoo($(this).val(), index + 1) + "<br>";
    });

    document.getElementById("data").innerHTML=output;
}

function switcharoo(value, count) {
    var uniqueID= '&lt;div class="example" id="FooBarDiv'+count+'"&gt;';
    var slot = "";

    switch (value){
        case 'foo':
            slot = "Foo";
            break;
        case 'bar':
            slot = "Bar";
            break;
    }
    slot += count + " is:<br>" + uniqueID;
    return slot.replace('**REPLACE-THIS**',count);
}
```

[Update using jquery with each method](http://jsfiddle.net/6U6S7/3/)
Be aware it could be optimized even more. but this should get your mind thinking about it. The switcharoo could be rewritten to just switch to only give a 'foo' or 'bar', which could then be placed in your return statement as well.

Comment: An array might be ideal, however, each element "string" is a block of code about 200-300 characters long. Wouldn't that muddle things up a bit?

Comment: if you are selecting all phase1's you could use the index +1 and loop through your elements that way  then your single function for switch would set count to the index + 1

Comment: hahaha... yeah... and that went RIGHT over my head. :-) Update answer perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

To reduce your example to the part the matters, lets try this:

```
var count= '**REPLACE-THIS**';
var uniqueID = '&lt;div class="example" id="FooBarDiv'+count+'"&gt;';
count = '1';

console.log(uniqueID);
// "&lt;div class="example" id="FooBarDiv**REPLACE-THIS**"&gt;"
```

So what's going on here?

You *do not* have a variable in a variable. You have two variables, and the first variable is used to construct the value assigned to the other variable. After this value is constructed, it is no longer connected to the variable that went into making it. It's now "baked into" the string set to `uniqueID`.

To fix this, you need compose the string *after* you have configured all it's inputs.

```
var count= '**REPLACE-THIS**';
if (something) {
  count = '1';
} else {
  count = '2';
}
var uniqueID = '&lt;div class="example" id="FooBarDiv'+count+'"&gt;';

console.log(uniqueID);
// "&lt;div class="example" id="FooBarDiv1"&gt;"
//                                       ^ or 2
```

---

Check this out, which demonstrates how `x` gets baked into the strings it generates.

```
var x;

x = 1;
var str1 = "x is "+ x;
x = 2;
var str2 = "x is "+ x;
x = 3;
var str3 = "x is "+ x;

console.log(str1); // x is 1
console.log(str2); // x is 2
console.log(str3); // x is 3
```

You can see the value of `x` changing, but the strings it's helping to create save the value of `x` that it was at the time the string was created. It's totally disconnected after creation.

[See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g8HK3/)

Comment: I see how it is two variables, but one is technically nested within the other though, right? --Not argumentative... Learning/understanding the nomenclature...   As for the instance here, can this if/else be wrapped within the case statement used as shown?

Comment: Nope. The varible is used to create a new string, and that value is baked in at that time. See my edit above

Answer (score -1):

if you want to re-interpolate a variable try this: (note eval is evil)

```
var a = 1;
var s = "'a = ' + a";
var r = eval(s);
console.log(r); // a = 1
a = 2;
r = eval(s);
console.log(r); // a = 2
```

Comment: why was this down voted... shall I not use it? it is foreign to me so clarification would be helpful...

Comment: `eval` is evil, as @phylax mentions. But using it to solve a simple logical error in the order of your operations is evil on purpose. This is way more complex than necessary and way more dangerous.